When using the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) v12.0 component, does the SDK for Java require at least version 11.0?
I'm making a xamarin forms  android 13 application for working with maps in C#.NET 5. Returns an error - When using the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) v12.0 component, the Java SDK package is required for at least version 11.0. I installed the java sdk version 21 and eclipse tamarin JDK with hotspot version 21 for this.In the settings of the visual studio 2019 environment, I set the path to jdk like this (C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.3.9-hotspot). JAVA_HOME system variables -C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.3.9-hotspot. in the Path - C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.3.9-hotspot\bin. what's the problem with it why doesn't the sdk see it? WorkingWithMaps.Android.csproj file -
`<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A81D3C7B-C0CD-4BB1-BF9E-C34BB1996E2A}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{c9e5eea5-ca05-42a1-839b-61506e0a37df}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WorkingWithMaps.Droid</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WorkingWithMaps.Android</AssemblyName>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v12.0</TargetFrameworkVersion> //I changed to V12.0
    <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
    <AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2012" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" Version="5.0.0.2012" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\styles.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WorkingWithMaps\WorkingWithMaps.csproj">
      <Project>{E71C3604-F980-496D-A3EE-D2E757746E91}</Project>
      <Name>WorkingWithMaps</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>`

AndroidManifest.xml - 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.workingwithmaps">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="30" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="WorkingWithMaps.Android">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>`





The information provided is not very clear. It is best to include the JAVA_HOME variable and the PATH variable. Also, try formatting those variables as code to make it more readable. It will help users to provide an answer.
